# Django-ratings and Jquery integration?

Tags: jquery, python, django

How do I make django-ratings work with Jquery?

What I'm trying to do is allow the user to select how ever many stars they want to give the product, and to have the corresponding rating processed asynchronously. I realize this is probably basic AJAX, and I apologize if this is a stupid question.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually converting to AJAX is as simple as replacing:

```
return HttpResponse(....)
```

with:

```
if request.is_ajax():
    return json_response
else:
    return HttpResponse(....)
```

or even requiring AJAX:

```
if request.is_ajax():
    return json_response
else:
    return HttpResponseForbidden('Only AJAX please!')
```

But, from what I see [here](https://github.com/dcramer/django-ratings/blob/master/djangoratings/views.py) there are some complext patterns for generating the actual response. So, you can either try working with that in jQuery AJAX response handler, by parsing the response - or you can write a decorator for AddRatingView.**call** that parses the response on the Python side and returns jQuery-friendly JSON.

I assume here that you don't want to mess a lot with the existing django-rating code, e.g. to preserve the option to upgrade it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but is your question from the javascript side or from the model side? From javascript, I used something like this

```
STARS_ELEMENT.stars({
    callback: function(ui, type, value){
        $.post('URL_ADDRESS', {rate: value},
            function(data){
                STARS_ELEMENT.stars("select",data);
            });                         
    }
```

Then in my view, I would have a function that captures that request and do this

```
p = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
p.rating.add(score=int(request.POST['rate']), user=request.user, ip_address=request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'])
p.save()
```

And use the request to send me back the most updated rate value. Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You are right,its a  basic Ajax, but you might have a complex algorithm to figure out the number of stars as